# Naming a column in pandas that is dependent on a function

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe, df.

```
a = len(series) - 6
df['M20'] = ...
```

It is irrelevant to show what the dataset series looks like, but len(series) = 26, so a = 20.

Is there a way of writing something like df['Ma'] **instead** of df['M20']?

I am running a monthly process, meaning next month len(series) would equal 27, a would equal 21, and so I don't want to have to manually change all of the 20s to 21s etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `format`:

```
a = len(series) - 6
df['M{}'.format(a)] = ...
```

---

```
df['M{}'.format(len(series) - 6)] = ...
```

Or `f-string`s for `python 3.6+`:

```
df[f'M{a}'] = ...
```

---

```
df[f'M{len(series) - 6}'] = ...
```